# Install PyAV on Windows

Tags: python, windows, gcc, ffmpeg, mingw

I got a problem building and thus setting up [PyAV](https://github.com/mikeboers/PyAV) 32-bit on Windows 8 (x64). I tried the workflow for Windows as indicated in their [documentation](http://mikeboers.github.io/PyAV/installation.html#on-windows), but did not succeed:

- I cross-compiled ffmpeg on Ubuntu 14.04 with the aid of [a script](https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers).
- I copied the `*shared-install` folder to Windows and set the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable to the corresponding `libs/pkgconfig` path.
- I copied the ffmpeg DLLs and its dependencies from the MinGW bin-folder to PyAV's `av` folder as mentioned in PyAV's docs.
- I ran `make build-mingw32` (where build-mingw32 is a recipe triggering python distutils like that: `CFLAGS=$(CFLAGS) LDFLAGS=$(LDFLAGS) python setup.py build_ext --inplace -c mingw32`)

Finally I run into trouble with that last command. When the build process tries to create `codec.pyd` there is a bunch of *undefined reference to _head_C_build27_cpython_PCBuild_libpython27_a* errors leading gcc to fail. See cmd output below:

[image]

I tried this on a fresh virtual machine running Windows 8.1 Pro having installed the MinGW toolchain including msys (I used the installer from mingw.org). I also tried the MinGW installer provided [here](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/). 
I hope someone already experienced similar issues using gcc and can help me with that!

Thanks in advance and best regards,
Michael

Comment: I tried to get pyAV to run on windows 7 64bit to no avail. Did you come across more extensive documentation in the mean time?